# include an attribute from the join table in a many to many relationship when fetching all associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, many-to-many, ruby-on-rails-5, join

I have this relationship of language and user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :languages, through: :language_users
    has_many :language_users
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users, through: :language_users
    has_many :language_users
end

class LanguageUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :user
end
```

LanguageUser class has an attribute ***level***. What I want is to get all the languages of a user which includes the level attribute (from LanguageUser class) for all the languages fetched by example- User.first.languages and it includes objects which have the language and the level.

Answer (score 0):

This query made it easy to fetch

```
i= User.first.languages.select('languages.*,language_users.level')
```

then just loop through it and access level by variable_name.level .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all the languages with level not null.

```
User.first.languages.where('language_users.level not NULL').select('languages.*,language_users.level')
```